# Как правильно реализовать валидацию введенных данных в классе, где есть конструктор?

Tags: php

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть класс User, в нем есть конструктор и я хочу сделать валидацию данных, которые будут передаваться в экземпляре класса. Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если конструктор (ли любая другая функция или метод) обнаруживает невалидные данные, то он должен бросить исключение и сообщить об этом вызывающему коду. А вызывающий код пусть уже думает, как это исключение обрабатывать

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: Можно тогда пожалуйста еще вопрос? А как тогда в таком случае обрабатывать данные из формы?

Comment: @ИванИванов Если мой вопрос решил Вашу проблему - отметьте его как верный. Если у Вас есть другой вопрос - задайте его в отдельном топике